# End User Training: Differences between SharePoint 2007 & SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, 2007, user, training

Less of a technical question but more of a governance one.  I'm finding it hard to take off my technical hat for this one.  Helpful responses will of course be marked as answers and upvoted accordingly

My end-users currently have a SharePoint 2007 intranet.  We are moving to SharePoint 2013.  Our training team have approached the technical team with a view of producing the end-user training but this is proving problematic.

I'm wondering what community members would flag-up in their own user base with such a scenario.  Some suggestions of looking at the differences between 2007 & 2010 and then 2010 & 2013 have come my way but I'd rather avoid this if possible, as I my end up including irrelevant information for the end user.

Comment: I'd rather start by looking at what they are trying to do with their intranet. Then you can focus on the changes that are relevant to them (teach them what they need rather than teach them what you know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider. First you need to train them on how to continue to do the things they need to know in order to continue to do their jobs effectively, like uploading documents, adding list items, creating lists, etc. The process may be the same, but the visual difference could be confusing or the steps may have changed slightly.

The second thing to consider is what are the new things they are getting by running on 2013. Are you going over Design Manager or Display Templates or workflow changes?

Focus on what has changed and what is new, don't even mention 2010 as it will only add confusion into the mix.

Answer (score 2):

Having done this migration (and training) a few times now, It depends a lot on what your users are expected to do.

Some of the changes for everyone:

Browser dependence (less reliance on IE)

Addition of the Ribbon, movement of almost all buttons into the ribbon.

Social changes (if you didn't have mySites before and you do now which seems common)

Changes in wordings (Explorer View > Open With Explorer, Permissions > Share With, Datasheet > Quick Edit)

Document uploading, new features for drag and drop, ellipsis menus.

Wikis, especially wiki page home page.

Some other items to consider:

InfoPath forms

SharePoint Designer Changes (Workflow 2010 and 2013 if available)

Answer (score 1):

Steven,

We did a similar migration last year with a large user base.  The biggest challange was to get everyone acquainted with the new user interface.

Before you start developing the training, it would be a great exercise to understand how your users use Share Point.

Few of the questions you may ask:-
1. What is the most common use of your SharePoint 2007.
2. Do you have any custom solutions (Server Object MOdel).
3. If any of your sites have Designer/jQuery/Workflows based solutions.

The best way to start would be to setup test site with all different template and start telling them the difference between the most common functionality and where things have moved.

Be ready for initial complains on SP2013 interfaces,  but then later everyone gets used to it.

Comment: one of the most common thing users struggle about is the Permission settings on File/Folder/Library/Site/SiteCollection.  Take this as an opportunity and train users to use 3 default groups (owners, members, visitors) wherever they can.  Use unique permission only when it is the only option.  Make sure your training contents are organized that way.